# Change language parameter for Google Map Iframe

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3

I am embedding this google map, but would like to change the language from Thai to English.

I read previously about adding the following parameters to the end of the code, but I have tried with no success.
?hl=
&hl=

```html
<iframe style="-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: blackscale(100%);" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d4710.0663131367055!2d100.5459341450774!3d13.882428806986514!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x30e283461efba1a3%3A0x8afb2e118473af38!2z4LiL4Lit4LiiIOC4q-C4oeC4ueC5iOC4muC5ieC4suC4meC5geC4geC4o-C4meC4lOC5jOC4hOC4suC5geC4meC4pSDguJXguLPguJrguKXguJrguLLguIfguJXguKXguLLguJQg4Lit4Liz4LmA4Lig4Lit4Lib4Liy4LiB4LmA4LiB4Lij4LmH4LiUIOC4meC4meC4l-C4muC4uOC4o-C4tSAxMTEyMA!5e0!3m2!1sth!2sth!4v1566888288318!5m2!1sth!2sth" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the below iframe code

```
 <iframe style="-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: blackscale(100%);" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d4710.0663131367055!2d100.5459341450774!3d13.882428806986514!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x30e283461efba1a3%3A0x8afb2e118473af38!2z4LiL4Lit4LiiIOC4q-C4oeC4ueC5iOC4muC5ieC4suC4meC5geC4geC4o-C4meC4lOC5jOC4hOC4suC5geC4meC4pSDguJXguLPguJrguKXguJrguLLguIfguJXguKXguLLguJQg4Lit4Liz4LmA4Lig4Lit4Lib4Liy4LiB4LmA4LiB4Lij4LmH4LiUIOC4meC4meC4l-C4muC4uOC4o-C4tSAxMTEyMA!5e0!3m2!1sth!2sth!4v1566888288318!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Whats changed?

The last parameter has been changed to `1sen!2sus` from `1sth!2sth`

Comment: @Light, If I'm right, he is not using the official google maps api. he is using a map share link which should not be used like this.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

**FIRST OPTION: Modifing your original frame**

Search and position on this code segment:

[image: example code to modify]

You need replace the two last "!1s**xx**" and "!2s**xx**" segments of code before the **width** parameter.

For set your language you need know the ISO 639-1 standard language codes: [Wikipedia ISO 639-1 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)

Here an example code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d25895663.485556163!2d-95.665!3d37.599999999999994!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x54eab584e432360b%3A0x1c3bb99243deb742!2sUnited%20States!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1673551620146!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
```

---

**SECOND OPTION: Changing the language of your map view**

Just go to the left menu at bottom where is "Language" and select your desired language.

[image: Language menu option]

After that, select the "Share & Embeb map". In the "Embed a map" tab just copy your frame code.

Comment: I confirm the first option, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `&language=` follow by the Language code [found here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport)

This is using `&language=en`

```html
<iframe style="-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: blackscale(100%);" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d4710.0663131367055!2d100.5459341450774!3d13.882428806986514!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x30e283461efba1a3%3A0x8afb2e118473af38!2z4LiL4Lit4LiiIOC4q-C4oeC4ueC5iOC4muC5ieC4suC4meC5geC4geC4o-C4meC4lOC5jOC4hOC4suC5geC4meC4pSDguJXguLPguJrguKXguJrguLLguIfguJXguKXguLLguJQg4Lit4Liz4LmA4Lig4Lit4Lib4Liy4LiB4LmA4LiB4Lij4LmH4LiUIOC4meC4meC4l-C4muC4uOC4o-C4tSAxMTEyMA!5e0!3m2!1sth!2sth!4v1566888288318&language=en!5m2!1sth!2sth" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```html
<iframe width="500" height="400" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?&hl=en!1sen!2sus &amp;q=22.9504487,76.0316206 &amp; q= India;&hl=es&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" &z=15&output=embed"0"></iframe>
```